# What is the format of this file?

Tags: file-format

What is the format of the file below?

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">

[{"ImageLinks":[{"Link":"http://b2b.ser3.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a4.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a5.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a6.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a7.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a8.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a9.jpg"},{"Link":"http://b2b.a20_1.png"}],"StockCode":"105-1020","Label":"UNIV05","Status":1,"Barcode":"0271","SubCategory":"BED","Category":"APPL","MainCategory":"HOME","Price":437.61,"SpecialPrice":0.0,"StockType":"Nu","Properties":"Univ Lt","Brand":"BathandBed","StockStatus":"N","QuantityInBox":0.0},
{"ImageLinks":[{"Link": ........ and continues
```

Comment: @Biffen Thanks struggling to make it acceptable

Comment: It’s easy if you read [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).